# Search through another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have an ability to search visit's info by typing pacient's name in searchbar.

I have following models:

```
class Pacient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :visits
    validates :name, presence: true
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :visits
end

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :pacient

  def self.search search
    where("id LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end      
end
```

In my visits controller:

```
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @visits = Visit.search(params[:search])
    else
      @visits = Visit.all
    end
  end
```

Here is my searchbar:

```
<%= form_tag(visits_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Name" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

This way I can find a visit, if I type visit's id in my searchbar. But I want to type a **pacient's name** and find the visit.

How should I modify my **index method** (visits_controller.rb) and **self.search method** (visit.rb) in order to make it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [SQL join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). In Rails you can do that with the [#joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) method:

```
def self.search search
  joins(:pacient).where("id LIKE ? OR pacients.name LIKE ?", "%{search}%", "%#{search}%")
end
```

This will try to find a visit either by the id or pacient's name.

Comment: thanks for you reply! Now when, I'm trying to search I get this error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: pacient.name`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is actually `pacients.name` in the plural. Just edited the answer.